# How to set list_per_page in ChoiceInline class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am following django 1.9 tutorial in which the author created the following class to display choices in admin panel.

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3
    list_per_page = 5 # not working
```

I want to limit choices to 5 per page, but i can't figure out how to do it.
I have successfully applied `list_per_page` to `QuestionAdmin` class like this

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # fields = ['pub_date', 'question_text']
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['question_text']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date']}),
    ]

    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

    list_display = ('question_text', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    search_fields = ['question_text']
    list_per_page = 5 # working perfectly
```

But the same is not working for `ChoiceInline` class.

Answer (score 0):

Django ModelAdmin Option: [list per page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page)

The difference between your two class is `ModelAdmin` and `InlineModelAdmin`.
As Django says:

> Set list_per_page to control how many items appear on each paginated admin change list page. By default, this is set to 100.

It will set the size of items displaying in `change_list`.

To limit the size of inline choices try this:

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3
    max_num = 5
```

Comment: So what to change to display only 5 choices per page ?

Comment: Try to play with `extra`, `min_num`, `max_num` attributes of your `ChoiceInline` Class

Comment: max_num doesn't affect the display count.  It's not obvious why - since if it doesn't limit the number displayed, what does it do?

Comment: max_num limits how many you could create via the admin interface. min number is how many you need to create, and extra is how many is there as a blank on top of the current values. None of them is relevant to this question with paginated inlines though.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `list_per_page` in your inline model, and it also doesnot make any sense, since this model is integrated as inline and it is displayed in changeview, not changelist.

Comment: It makes sense to want to paginate the inlines in the change view.  I have an account with a balance.  I want to see the transactions included to create the balance.   Now that I have a lot of transactions, I'd like to speed up the search by only showing the newest 20.